# Mutually independent events task

Tags: probability, statistics

We have $P(A) = 0.3$, $P(B) = 0.4$, $P(C)=0.5$. We know that the events are mutually independent. 
We are looking for 
$$P( \overline{\rm A} \cap \overline{\rm B} \cap   C) =?$$
My guess is $0.7 \cdot 0.6 \cdot 0.5 = 0.21$. But this wasn't the answer. Any tips?

Comment: Why do you say it is not correct?

Comment: it wasn't on the answer list.

Comment: What is the answer that you are comparing it with?

Comment: I don't know the correct answer.

Comment: What were on the answer list?

Comment: I don't remember them all. 0.4, 0.21, 0.14 , 0,8 and others.

Comment: So you're saying it wasn't on the answer list, but at the same time it was. Maybe it was [Schrödinger's cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat) passing by?

Comment: my mistake. It was 0.22 on the answer list.

Answer (score 0):

0.21 is the correct answer.

If $A$, $B$ and $C$ are independent, then $\overline{\rm A}$, $\overline{\rm B}$ and $C$ are independent.

$P( \overline{\rm A} \cap \overline{\rm B} \cap   C) = P( (\overline{\rm {A \cup B}}) \cap   C)$
$=P( A \cup B \cup   C) - P({A \cup B})$
$=P(C) - P(B \cap C) - P({A \cap C}) + P( A \cap B \cap   C)$
$=P(C)-P(A).P(C)-P(B).P(C)+P(A).P(B).P(C)$
$=(1-P(A)).(1-P(B)).P(C)$
$=P(\overline {\rm A}).P(\overline {\rm B}).P(C)$